# Invalid Key Hash. The Key XYZ Doesn't Match

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I understand that similar questions have been asked, and answered, but what I want to know is why this keeps happening to me. To solve this issue for me, I have to delete the application in Facebook, then recreate it. It works until I disconnect the phone, then I get the same issue. I have tried adding the key that supposedly doesn't match, as well as generating a debug key using `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

I have also tried using the code:

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.org.package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String sign = Base64
                        .encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", sign);

            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
```

I have gone tons of these questions, but I can't seem to figure out how to keep this problem from coming back, without having to delete the project every time I reconnect my device to the computer. Oddly enough, every time I get the error, it's the same keyhash.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't written your application package name instead of `com.org.package` in above posted code.

Well, Give it a try by changing package name to your application's package name...

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "YOUR PACKAGE NAME HERE", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```